# Configure different $projectroot on one Git-Web

Tags: git, apache, gitweb

I have a question about GitWeb configuration.

Following this manual I've installed GitWeb http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-GitWeb

But I need to configure apache or etc/gitweb.conf for the following, e.g.

- domain sub1.domain.com should use $projectroot = "/var/www/git_fsq/";
- domain sub2.domain.com should use $projectroot = "/var/www/git_2/";
- etc.

I don't have any free memory on the server to install something that can help me to hide some projects from some users =)

Could you help me how I can configure this in gitweb.conf or Apache VirtualHost settings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use different name based virtual host

Sample config below

```
    ServerName www.cart.com
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/gitweb

    
        SetEnv GITWEB_CONFIG  /home/gitmaster/gitweb.conf 
        Options FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
        AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
```

Comment: I've got a problem "File does not exist: /var/www/gitweb/NAME.git" on clonning this repo.

Comment: >> Repo itself in in  /var/www/gitrepo/NAME.git and I can't see where I an configure this

Comment: check permissions, if apache user (www-data or apache) can read you repository